# how to get the slected value from select onemenu it canbe placed in data table

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

my xhtml is:

Role Details

```
                </f:facet>
        <p:column headerText="Roleid">

        <p:selectOneMenu id="user_page" value="#{ps.roleid}" >
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One"   />
            <f:selectItems value="#{one.p}" var="vv" itemLabel="#{vv.roleid}"
                itemValue="#{vv.roleid}" />

        </p:selectOneMenu>
```

my bean class is:

Permissions.java

```
private String roleid;

public String getRoleid()
 {

return roleid;

}
public void setRoleid(String roleid)
 {

    this.roleid = roleid;

}
```

i place select one menu  component in data table how can i get the value of selected from  the select one menu component

Answer (score 1):

you need to put listener under selectOneMenu. you can pass the row number with f:setpropertyActionListener to target property and get it working..

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="user_page" value="#{ps.roleid}" >
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One"   />
        <f:selectItems value="#{one.p}" var="vv" itemLabel="#{vv.roleid}"
            itemValue="#{vv.roleid}" />
       <p:ajax update="fieldId" event="change"
                listener="#{ps.onChangeMethod}" >
             <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ps.additionalProperty}" value="value_here"/>
       </p:ajax>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

More on client side : [Getting selected value of a SelectOneMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824178/getting-selected-value-of-a-selectonemenu)